# How can I apply jQuery .css style to descendant div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to figure the issue out for past few hours but can't get it to work.

I'm having that div that contains 3 other divs:

```
<div id="main" class="box">                             
    <div class="index"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="options"></div>
</div>
```

Ultimately I want div with class .options to show after clicking on the div id "main", using jQuery, by first finding relevant descendant and than applying either .show() or toggle() function. Unfortunatelly I can't get it to work, and even trying to apply simple .css style change fails to work. Here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').on(mouseenter: function(event) {
        $(this).find('.options').css("background" , "red")})
});
```

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k1uf6zw/)

Any clues?

Comment: Surely you'll notice that your code results in a syntax error.

Comment: To whomever voted down, I'd appreciate if you don't do it. Missing detail such as colon instead of coma can happen, and it doesn't mean lack of doing research on my side. After all it doesn't take genius to calculate which is faster: fixing syntax error, or creating tread inlcuding working js fiddle (which means removing hundreds lines of code to make it clear for the reader).

Comment: Whoever it was has a good reason to do so; lack of research. Debugging is part of that process and you clearly didn't do any debugging.

Comment: And obviously "debugging" is the knowledge about which we are all born with. Some people...

Comment: Downvotes are on content, not people. Your ability to debug isn't relevant to the downvote. Don't take downvotes so personally.

Comment: Downvotes lower your reputation and that limits actions you can undertake on SO site. So maybe in theory downvote is about question, but in reality it's a person who gets punished, even though prior to asking the question he did all he could to solve the issue himself. Maybe not all, after all he could have spent another 12 hours trying to find the bug. But that's not the point of the website like SO, is it?

Comment: right, SO is all about the content. all actions that take place are supposed to focus on the question and the answer. A downvote on a question reduces the visibility of the question, which in this case is a good thing since this question is one that will not help any future visitors since it is just a syntax issue. We wouldn't want this question showing up for someone who is searching for a css related question.

Comment: "We"? Having wasted 3 hours trying to find the issue that has been addressed in minutes after posting, I would LOVE to have this question appear as a first result in google.

Comment: @user3210787 for future reference http://api.jquery.com/css/ and http://www.jslint.com/ and using the console helps greatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your code is amost right, but the problem is the JQuery event binder sintax.

Read the [**JQuery .on() Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

The syntax for the method is:

> **.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )**

Being the *events* argument's description:

> **events**
>   **Type:** *String*
>   One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

So, the first argument is a string. You've passed in a way that makes no sense:

```
$('#main').on(mouseenter: function(event) {
```

Where it should be:

```
$('#main').on("mouseenter", function(event) {
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3k1uf6zw/)

Comment: Ah, that bloody coma... I centuple checked syntax whether I missed bracket or semicolon at the end and completelly missed that part. All answers pointed the problem out perfectly, so thanks to all of you guys, yet this answer seems to be the most universal and explanatory. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').on("click", function() {
        $(this).find('.options').css("background" , "red");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For mouseenter it should look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html').on('mouseenter','#main', function(event) {
        $(this).find('.options').css("background" , "red")})
});
```

For click just replace 'mouseenter' with 'click'